# Puppeteer Throwing Error "Cannot extract value when objectId is given"

Tags: node.js, web-scraping, puppeteer, google-chrome-headless

Started getting this error today in Puppeteer running on Ubuntu. Never had this happen before, and our code has not changed, just updated Puppeteer. Anyone ideas?

> Error: Cannot extract value when objectId is given
> at assert (/root/bot/node_modules/puppeteer-core/lib/cjs/puppeteer/util/assert.js:28:15)
> at valueFromRemoteObject (/root/bot/node_modules/puppeteer-core/lib/cjs/puppeteer/common/util.js:242:28)
> at createClientError (/root/bot/node_modules/puppeteer-core/lib/cjs/puppeteer/common/util.js:122:16)
> at CDPPage._CDPPage_handleException (/root/bot/node_modules/puppeteer-core/lib/cjs/puppeteer/common/Page.js:894:94)
> at /root/bot/node_modules/puppeteer-core/lib/cjs/puppeteer/common/Page.js:186:100
> at /root/bot/node_modules/puppeteer-core/lib/cjs/third_party/mitt/index.js:3:248
> at Array.map ()
> at Object.emit (/root/bot/node_modules/puppeteer-core/lib/cjs/third_party/mitt/index.js:3:232)
> at CDPSessionImpl.emit (/root/bot/node_modules/puppeteer-core/lib/cjs/puppeteer/common/EventEmitter.js:87:22)
> at CDPSessionImpl._onMessage (/root/bot/node_modules/puppeteer-core/lib/cjs/puppeteer/common/Connection.js:441:18)
> Node.js v18.7.0
> Exit!

Worked On
Ubuntu: 20.04.3
Node: 14.17.5
puppeteer: 9.1.1
puppeteer-extra: 3.3.4
puppeteer-extra-plugin-stealth: 2.11.1

NOT Working On
Ubuntu: 22.10 
Node: 18.7.0
puppeteer: 20.2.1
puppeteer-extra: 3.3.6
puppeteer-extra-plugin-stealth: 2.11.2

Looks like its a version specific bug.

```
  const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

  const withBrowser = async (fn) => {
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
      headless: true,
      args: ['--no-sandbox', '--disable-setuid-sandbox', '--proxy-server=zproxy.lum-superproxy.io:22225', '--window-size=' + vWidth + ',' + vHeight],
      ignoreDefaultArgs: ['--disable-extensions', '--disable-default-apps', '--disable-component-extensions-with-background-pages']
    });
    try {
      return await fn(browser);
    } finally {
      await browser.close();
    }
  }

  const withPage = (browser) => async (fn) => {
    const page = await browser.newPage();
    await page.setViewport({ width: vWidth, height: vHeight, deviceScaleFactor: 1});
    try {
      return await fn(page);
    } finally {
      await page.close();
      await browser.close();
    }
  }

  const results = await withBrowser(async (browser) => {
      return withPage(browser)(async (page) => {
        try {
response = await page.goto(pageUrl);
    .catch((err) => {
      console.error(err);
    });
```

Comment: Please share a [mcve] along with your Puppeteer versions before and after the upgrade. Thanks.

Comment: I downgraded puppeteer to 19.5.2 and it seems to be working

Comment: I also downgraded to 19.5.2, seems to be working now.

Comment: The following issue was raised in GitHub (https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/issues/10224), with commenters suggesting rolling back to 20.1.2 (which worked for me). The issue seems to be fixed in the latest version (20.4.0), which I just upgraded to and have been testing for an hour or so.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like this is a bug in Puppeteer as of version 2.1.x

https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/issues/10224